# Oracle SQL comma separated parameter in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

My table looks like:

```
+----------+----------+
|stud_id   |stud_name |
+----------+----------+
|101       |A         |
|102       |B         |
|103       |C         |
|104       |D         |
|105       |E         |
+----------+----------+
```

My query

```
SELECT * FROM students_tbl stud WHERE stud.stud_id IN (:s_id);
```

When I input 102 it returns:

```
+----------+----------+
|stud_id   |stud_name |
+----------+----------+
|102       |B         |
+----------+----------+
```

just as expected.

Is there a way where I can input multiple values like 102,103,104 and results like this?:

```
+----------+----------+
|stud_id   |stud_name |
+----------+----------+
|102       |B         |
|103       |C         |
|104       |D         |
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/57753759/1509264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr` with `connect by` for it.

```
SELECT * FROM students_tbl stud WHERE stud.stud_id IN 
(Select regexp_substr(:s_id,'[^,]+', 1,level)
From dual
Connect by regexp_substr(:s_id,'[^,]+', 1, level) is not null);
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to split the value of the bind variable; a faster solution is to see if the id (plus surrounding delimiters) is a sub-string of the bind variable (with leading and trailing delimiters):

```sql
select *
from   students_tbl
where  ','||:s_id||',' LIKE ','||stud_id||','
```

Comment: I'd just point out that this construct prevents you from using an index on `stud_id`.  Probably not critical if the table has a few hundred students.  If the table has a few hundred thousand students, though, that's going to get expensive.

Comment: If you really wanted to you could pass `:s_id` as a `TABLE OF NUMBER` and use `WHERE stud_id MEMBER OF :s_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will ask you for 3 input values and you will get desired result

```
SELECT * FROM students_tbl stud WHERE stud.stud_id IN (:s_id,:s_id1,:s_id2);
```