# Using IN operator in comma-separated list in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose my input is "1, 2, 3"
and I want to use `IN(1, 2, 3)` but I am not able to.
In MYSQL I could have used `FIND_IN_SET` but here I am not able to find anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to query a comma separated column for a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212282/is-it-possible-to-query-a-comma-separated-column-for-a-specific-value) or [Oracle SQL comma separated parameter in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57849397/oracle-sql-comma-separated-parameter-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to split the string and can use `LIKE` (making sure you also match the surrounding delimiters):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ', ' || :your_list || ', ' LIKE '%, ' || column_to_match || ', %'
```

Which for your hard-coded list would be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ', 1, 2, 3, ' LIKE '%, ' || column_to_match || ', %'
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (name, column_to_match) AS
SELECT 'A', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 4 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NAME | COLUMN_TO_MATCH |
> | --- | --- |
> | A | 1 |
> | B | 2 |
> | C | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a7d38a501cfe438512f722634ab51c81)*

Comment: @MTO, I am getting these values ‘1,2,3,4’ as an input to my procedure and I need to pick the data from a certain table matching these values but I can’t use these directly like IN (‘1,2,3,4’). Therefore I need a way to covert them to number type to use it as IN (1,2,3,4)

Comment: @AdityaDhiman You cannot do that as you are passing in a single string value and not a list of numbers and it is impossible to convert from one to the other. As I said in the answer, use `LIKE` to perform a sub-string match (including the delimiters in the match).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to split that string into rows.

On Scott's sample schema:

```
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Here's how:

```
SQL> select * from dept
  2  where deptno in (select regexp_substr('&&par_deptno', '[^,]+', 1, level)
  3                   from dual
  4                   connect by level <= regexp_count('&&par_deptno', ',') + 1
  5                  );
Enter value for par_deptno: 10,30,40

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
        30 SALES          CHICAGO

SQL>
```

---

Depending on tool you use, you might have to change substitution variable with a bind variable, i.e. use

```
... select regexp_substr(:par_deptno, ...
```

instead.

Comment: I am getting these values ‘1,2,3,4’ as an input to my procedure and I need to pick the data from a certain table matching these values but I can’t use these directly like IN (‘1,2,3,4’). Therefore I need a way to covert them to number type to use it as IN (1,2,3,4)

Comment: If you have values enclosed into single quotes, **remove them** first; the rest of query remains *as is*: `select regexp_substr(replace(:par_deptno, chr(39), null), '[^,]+', 1, level) ...`